# Wait until Outlook responds

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

This works if I only run this Sub, but before that I have Subs to open a file, copy data from it, create Piv. Tables, etc.

I want to run the whole process together. Sometimes Excel closes and the whole is not done.

Is there a possibility to set in VBA, that until the mail creation, attaching the file and inserting a table is done in Outlook, it will not continue with the next action?

Tried `.display True`, also tried to insert waiting time, but sometimes it is not working.

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Sub Mail_send()
    
    If MsgBox("Do you want to send out the report?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        GoTo skip
    End If
    
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim rg1 As Range
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim emailRng1 As Range, cl1 As Range
    Dim sTo1 As String
    Dim emailRng2 As Range, cl2 As Range
    Dim sTo2 As String
    Dim MaxD As Date
    
    ' Set Max Date
    MaxD = GetMaxDate(Sheets("Raw data").Columns(33))
        
    ' emailRng1 - To name recipients
    Sheets("Mail loops and contact persons").Activate
        
    Set emailRng1 = Sheets("Mail loops and contact persons").Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        
    For Each cl1 In emailRng1
        sTo1 = sTo1 & ";" & cl1.Value
    Next
    
    sTo1 = Mid(sTo1, 2)
        
    ' emailRng2 - CC name recipients    
    Set emailRng2 = Sheets("Mail loops and contact persons").Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
        
    For Each cl2 In emailRng2
        sTo2 = sTo2 & ";" & cl2.Value
    Next
        
    sTo2 = Mid(sTo2, 2)
       
    ' -----------------------------------------------------
    Sheets("Table").Select
    Set rg1 = Sheets("Table").Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(7, 8))
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
          
    str1 = "<BODY style = font-size:12pt-family:Calibri>" & _
      "Dear all,<br><br> Please find the productivity report for the last working day."
        
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .to = sTo1
        .CC = sTo2
        .Subject = "Productivity Report" & " " & Format(MaxD - 1, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        .Display
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = str1 & RangetoHTML(rg1) & .HTMLBody
        .Display True    
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    End With
    
skip:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

I'm also using two functions:

```vb
'' Get Max Date
Function GetMaxDate(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim cur_date As Date, arr As Variant, d As Variant
    arr = rng ' get all the data into an array to improve performance (one operation of reading data from the sheet)
    For Each d In arr
        If IsDate(d) Then ' we check whether the next value can be a date
            cur_date = CDate(d) '
            If GetMaxDate < cur_date Then GetMaxDate = cur_date ' select max date
        End If
    Next
    If Not IsEmpty(GetMaxDate) Then
        GetMaxDate = Format(GetMaxDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Else
        GetMaxDate = "#NODATE"
    End If
End Function

'' Convert Range to HTML
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    
' Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    
' Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
         .Publish (True)
    End With

' Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
      "align=left x:publishsource=")

' Close TempWB
    
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Delete the htm file we used in this function

    Kill TempFile
    
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "attaching the a file and inserting a table is not done in outlook"? Do you mean the user is supposed to do that?

Comment: It's done automatically by the VBA. It's attaching the workbook, in which the macro is working, and also inserting a table from the sheets into the Mail.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Still, what exactly are you asking? What is your code that you cannot make work?

Comment: I posted it below, It's working, if only I just run this Sub, but before that I have also other Subs to Open a file, Copy data from it, create Piv. Tables, etc. But I want to run the whole process together... Sometimes it's creating a new mail, attach the file, copy the table from it, running smoothly, but sometimes the Excel is just closing and the whole is not done.

Comment: If `Mail_send` works when run separately, I suggest code that calls `Mail_send` is relevant to this question.

Comment: fyi - Even if there is no impact. Although `On Error Resume Next` followed by `With OutMail` is an often seen structure it is inappropriate 100% of the time. Delete `On Error Resume Next` in `Sub Mail_send`. If there is an error you may fix it or apply appropriate error handling. Here it is 200% inappropriate as there is no matching `On Error GoTo 0`.

Comment: I will try,  it's a strange case, because now I separated the whole process for 2 steps, 1st is doing the piv.tables, calculating, etc., the 2nd is the mail sending, and like this it's working properly...

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the process is not interrupted and Excel is not closed while Outlook is automated I'd suggest opening a modal form (for example, with a progress bar) in Excel preventing users from closing it.

Comment: A modal form would stop the code AFAIK

Comment: The code can be run from the form, so it will never stop anything.

Comment: Nice idea indeed